# Pass keyboard input data to the view controller

Tags: cocoa, swift

My view controller needs to respond to keyboard input, but the only way I know of to get keyboard input is to subclass `NSView` and override `keyDown`. That's fine, but I don't know how to get that data back to the view controller. Is there an easier way of getting keyboard input to my view controller, and if not, how do I pass the keyboard data I receive from the view to the view controller?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming use of common controls**
Your controller should implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` (or `UITextViewDelegate`) and 'listen in' on text changes.  You then assign your controller as the `delegate` to the `UITextField` (or `UITextView`); once assigned the control calls your controller and you do what you please with the text.

One common approach is to implement the delegate method:

```
optional func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

and then in that method use `textField.text` to get the `String` which you can then assign to some property in your controller.

**Lower Level** If you are not using common controls, then your View Controller should be a subclass of NSResponder.  You implement the methods `keyUp` and `keyDown` to be notified of key events.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but I'm not using Cocoa Touch, I'm using Cocoa.

Comment: Also, I never said anything about text fields. I don't have a text field, I just want my view to respond to input.

Comment: Okay, point taken.  Are you not using NSTextField, or similar, as well?  Nor NSTextFieldDelegate?

Comment: Well, I do have a label, (which is an NSTextField), but it's not editable (because it's a label). Perhaps I could use that to receive input? I've never done anything like that before, I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: I sounds like you should find an existing control, like a NSTextField, to do the hard job (spelling, selects, deletes, voice input) of acquiring key strokes.  Good luck.